# Why am I not able to use promise in my basic react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I am fairly new to react and I was experimenting on axios get requests . So What I am trying to do is that I have a json file in my public folder and I am making a get axios request to the location of that file and then I am printing the result in an array .

The first method worked pretty smoothly . A demo of the function is given below

[image: Method which worked.]

The output is given below:

[image: The correct output]

And as evident , this approach worked pretty fine.

However I also made a class named Fetch inside a service.js file . This class had a method named fetch which used axios to make a get request.

The demo of this class is given below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

class Fetch extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }
    fetch()
    {
        console.log("Hi i am in fetch of service....");
        axios.get('./config.json').then(response=>{
            var x=response.data;
            console.log("----------------------------------------->"+JSON.stringify(x));
            
            return x;
        },(err)=>{
            return err;

        })
        
    }
}

export default Fetch;
```

I imported this class in another js file and made an object of this class to call the fetch method.A demo of my usage is given below:

[image]

However when I tried to do this , I got the following error:

[image: The error]

What am I doing wrong ? If it worked for the first time , then why is this not working now?

Comment: Please post text copied from your editor instead of pictures of your editor.

Comment: In your `Fetch` class, return the axios request from the `fetch()` function

Comment: @Kobe...I am storing the response in a variable and returning it.Is this what u mean...??

Comment: @AshutoshKumar see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving that error because nothing is returned from `Fetch.fetch()`, let alone a promise.

You are trying to call `.then()` on a void function, so you will not be able to access the response.

In your `Fetch` class, return the axios request from the `fetch()` function:

```js
fetch() {
    return axios.get('/config.json').then(response => {
        // your code
    })
}
```